# Review-beta shows no suggested edits even though there are some

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

I see the counter of the pending edits, but there are no pending edits in the new review: https://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits says “There are no items for you to review.”

[image: screenshot]

It started happening today (UTC time); yesterday it was fine. The counter redirects me to review-beta/suggested-edits.

On the old review page https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits the suggestions are visible.

#### Update

It seems the new page sees the pending edits after the old page, which means the suggested edits are there, but the new page doesn't show them. If I change the URL, and I replace review-beta/suggested-edits with review/suggested-edits, the pending edits are shown, and I can approve, or reject them.

The first time, I have been able to see the pending edits after I kept clicking on the edit counter. I cannot say what caused the suggested edits to finally appear.

Comment: They are there, for some reason that panel doesn't see them. They can be accessed from the [old suggested edits tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), though. I've been meaning to file this but haven't cared. The issue is that the new review "task" doesn't see them. xP

Comment: It seems they appear with a delay. Keeping to click on the counter, I was finally able to see them.

Comment: Interesting, they'd been up there for quite a while, so that's quite some delay then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new review queues are currently refreshed every 20 minutes. So there'll generally be a delay between something becoming eligible for review and actually showing up in the queue.

Comment: Whoa.  You're close to becoming Meta's second 100K user.  Are you ready to fill those shoes???  :-)

Comment: I'm stocking up on socks for padding... And hey - congrats on the Wired interview ;-)

Comment: Oh, you saw that ;)  Was my pleasure.  I have nothing but good things to say about SO.  In fact, my unhealthy addiction to your site in the second half of 2011 landed me my current dream job (which ironically leaves me no time to answer questions).