# Suggested Edits flag indicator is seemingly out-of-sync

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The number of edits is shown when there are no pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139624/the-number-of-edits-is-shown-when-there-are-no-pending-edits)

Just a heads up, since this is a good time for reporting bugs (Beta!). The "suggested edits pending approval" count seems to be off. When I click it to view the edits, the tool reports that there are no items for me to review. I believe some users can see the suggested edits, because the number continues to update, increasing or decreasing over time.

[image: screenshot]