# What happened to the "suggested edits" page?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta)

Until recently, when I clicked on the "suggested edits pending approval" icon at the top of stackoverflow.com, it would show me a list of suggested edits (30 or so, or all of them if there are fewer than 30).

Now the page layout is a bit different, and it only shows one. I have to click the "Not Sure" button if I want to see another suggested edit.

If this is a bug, when will it be fixed? If it's a feature -- same question.

Comment: Note the URL - it is the new [review-beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta). Still has some teething problems...

Comment: @Oded: Ah, I didn't notice that. If I remove the "review-" from the URL, I get the old version -- which, at least so far, I like a lot better. Scrolling through a list is much more convenient than explicitly ignoring one at a time without being able to see any others.

Comment: Well, the rationale for this new page has been posted in the announcement.

Comment: @Oded: Hmm. I just read the announcement, and I don't see anything about showing just one edit at a time vs. the old longer list.

Comment: Yeah, that's not mentioned at all. You can add an answer to the post asking for a list. It was probably done to help with performance and to minimize the occasions of reviewing something that others are reviewing at the same time (so your "vote" might not get cast).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139816/167210

Answer (score 3):

Call it a feature - the review process is being updated, as [Geoff posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta).

However, it still has some [bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139624/the-number-of-edits-is-shown-when-there-are-no-pending-edits).

The old (?) page is still accessible - just drop the `-beta` from the URL.